# Custom TextField Swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui, textfield

How can I create a text field like the one shown in the figure? with background of that color and white line?

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

@available(iOS 16.0, *)
struct SecondView: View {
    @State var nome = ""
    @State var cognome = ""

    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            ZStack {
                Color(red: 57 / 255, green: 63 / 255, blue: 147 / 255)
                Text("Ora tocca ai tuoi dati")
                    .font(Font.custom("Rubik", size: 22)).foregroundColor(Color.white).font(Font.body.bold()).padding(.bottom, 300).font(Font.headline.weight(.light))

                Text("Per iniziare ad usare MyEntZo completa i campi qui sotto").multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .font(Font.custom("Rubik", size: 18)).foregroundColor(Color.white).font(Font.body.bold()).padding(.bottom, 80).font(Font.headline.weight(.light))

                TextField("Nome", text: $nome, axis: .vertical)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                    .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
                    .padding().padding(.bottom, 20).padding(.top, 110).scaledToFill()
                    .underline()

                TextField("Cognome", text: $nome, axis: .vertical)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                    .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
                    .padding().padding(.bottom, 20).padding(.top, 190).scaledToFill()
                    .underline()
                
            
                    Button(action: {
                        print("sign up bin tapped")
                    }){
                        Text("Continua")
                            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .font(.system(size: 18))
                            .padding()
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .overlay(
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                                    .stroke(Color.green, lineWidth: 2)
                            )
                    }
                    .background(Color.green)
                    .cornerRadius(25).frame(width: geo.size.width - 50, height: 100)
                    .padding(.top, 300)
                }
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea()
        
    }
}

struct SecondView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SecondView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom text field that wraps a regular `TextField`, passing in the `@State` as a `@Binding`, e.g.

```
struct CustomTextField: View {
    
    let placeholder: String
    @Binding var text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField(placeholder, text: $text)
                .padding(.bottom, 4)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            Color.white
                .frame(height: 2)
        }
        .padding([.top, .bottom, .trailing])
        .background(.blue)
    }
}
```

which you can use like:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var nome: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // etc
            CustomTextField(placeholder: "Nome", text: $nome)
            // etc
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
struct SecondView: View {
    @State var nome = ""
    @State var cognome = ""

    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            ZStack {
                Color(red: 57 / 255, green: 63 / 255, blue: 147 / 255)
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Ora tocca ai tuoi dati")
                        .font(Font.custom("Rubik", size: 22))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .bold()
                        .padding()
                        .font(Font.headline.weight(.light))
                    Text("Per iniziare ad usare MyEntZo completa i campi qui sotto").multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .font(Font.custom("Rubik", size: 18)).foregroundColor(Color.white).font(Font.body.bold()).padding(.bottom, 80).font(Font.headline.weight(.light))
                
                    TextField("Nome", text: $nome, prompt: Text("Nome").foregroundColor(.white.opacity(0.7)))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .background(.white)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 2)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                    TextField("Cognome", text: $cognome, prompt: Text("Cognome").foregroundColor(.white.opacity(0.7)))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding([.horizontal, .top])
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .background(.white)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 2)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        print("sign up bin tapped")
                    }){
                        Text("Continua")
                            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .font(.system(size: 18))
                            .padding()
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .overlay(
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                                    .stroke(Color.green, lineWidth: 2)
                            )
                    }
                    .background(Color.green)
                    .cornerRadius(25).frame(width: geo.size.width - 50, height: 100)
                    .padding(.top)
                    
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
                
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You should explain what changes you made to the original code and how it solved the problem. Code only answers are discouraged here since they don't necessarily give enough context to help future readers.